# How to automatically refresh url once in a day on hosting site

Tags: asp.net

I have made a web application that sends email automatically when page loads. But how can I load my Default.aspx page automatically once a day on go daddy server where my website is hosted?

Comment: Whatever solution you choose to poll your website, you also need to check that it has not already been run on the same day. Otherwise you may find yourself sending dozens of emails per day.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie  you are right..but later i changed page url that is not ping by any one..one refresh once in a day and send email automatically to find from database record.

Answer (score 1):

The overall problem is "How do I send an email every 24 hours". This really has nothing to do with web pages, except that is your current trigger mechanism. Better off changing your question to cover the overall aim, however...

You are better off having a separate task. One way is to use cache expiry as described here: https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

1. At startup, add an item to the HttpRuntime.Cache with a fixed expiration.
2. When cache item expires, do your work, such as WebRequest or what have you.
3. Re-add the item to the cache with a fixed expiration.

### Code (from that site):

```
private static CacheItemRemovedCallback OnCacheRemove = null;

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddTask("DoStuff", 60 * 60 * 24);
}

private void AddTask(string name, int seconds)
{
    OnCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, seconds, null, 
        DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
        CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
}

public void CacheItemRemoved(string k, object v, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
{
    // do stuff here if it matches our taskname, like WebRequest
    // re-add our task so it recurs
    AddTask(k, Convert.ToInt32(v));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options

If you have use of another machine that is always on, you can have a simple scheduled task or cron (depending on if it is windows or linux) to ping the url

If you have a free tier AWS or Azure account you can set yup schedules tasks, or one of the baove on those

Use a free monitoring service like [pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/free/)  this will ping every x minutes up to an hour i think, but there are others out there like pingability.com that can do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have your page opened, you can add html metatag `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="86400"/>` to the head, which will reload it once a day.

Comment: but i want to send BirthDay email automatically on 12.00AM and my site is hosted on godaddy server. so can i continuously open my page?

Comment: Although possibly not obvious, the problem is *not* getting a page to refresh every day. It is about getting the page loaded (so that it can refresh in the first place) i.e. by polling the website via some external stimulus every 24 hours.